# How to check TableviewCell value isEmpty or not on button click to post data Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have implemented tableview data and successfully printing on mobile screen. Actually I need to check tableview's specific cell that it is the required field and its mandatory to be filled on Button click. 
Button Event is performing to post data on another `viewController`. I tried to implement in `cellForRow` but in this I can only change color.

How to possible to check cell is empty on buttonClick before posting ad generate alert or print.

Model:

```
var AppData : Unit?

AppData have sectionList and sectionList have items then items have different values
```

**cellForRow** for getting data:

```
AppData?.sectionList?[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row].textField ??
```

Code which I tried in cellForRow tableView:

```
if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 2) {

            let chkVal = AppData?.sectionList?[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row].textValue
            if chkVal == nil {
                grayBox.backgroundColor = ("#e5cfcf").toColor()

            }
        }
```

Comment: where is that button action ?

Comment: Is the button present on every row?

Comment: @Rob13  not every row. Only one button just tabbar at the bottom to accept or reject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender:UIButton) {
   if let chkVal = AppData?.sectionList?[2].items?[2].textValue {
       // there is a value
    } 
    else { 
      // nil value 
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible I can change the `backgroundcolor` of this cell ?

Comment: its working but how can I update this value to `AppData`

Comment: set it like `AppData?.sectionList?[2].items?[2].textValue = someValue`

Comment: yes done that. Any way to set background color for this cell ?